# How do I correctly blur a UIView using a UIVisualEffectView?

Tags: iphone, swift, uiview, blur

So I have a form that is presented modally when I click on a button. This is how it looks.

[image]

I would like to blur the grayish area that you can see from the picture above. My initial set up is: I have a UIView, called backgroundView and I have another UIView called addIncomeFormView. 
Here is the initial Storyboard layout. (I believe that the addIncomeFormView is the child of backgroundView.)

[image]

In my Cocoa file I did this.

```
@IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView! {
   didSet {
      backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
      let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
      let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
      blurEffectView.frame = backgroundView.bounds
      blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
      backgroundView.addSubview(blurEffectView)

    }
}
```

The result of doing that is that when I click the button I get this.

[image]

**How can I get the addIncomeFormView (UIView) to not be blurred or in other words to sit on top of the blurred UIView?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line: `backgroundView.addSubview(blurEffectView)`
to this: `backgroundView.insertSubview(blurEffectView, at: 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the blur view to the back after adding it

```
backgroundView.sendSubviewToBack(blurEffectView)
```